# Get the missing months count as zero (0) and populate into the DataTable

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, c#-4.0

Here's my sql query

```
select Month,count(id) transactions from `tbl_test` where id=" + id + " and Month is not NULL and Year = " + Convert.ToInt32(currentYear) + " group by Month;
```

Month is varchar
and id is int
I am using mysql.

Popllating it into DataTable

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);
```

The result I am getting is like

```
Month transactions 
May     122
December 178
```

And the result I want is like

```
Month transactions 
January    0
February   0
March      0
April      0
May        122
June       0
July       0
August     0
September  0
October    0
November   0
December   178
```

I have created another table with all the months and trying to join the 2. But of no use (I guess because of the where clause in the sql statement). Kindly help.

**PS: I would prefer not to change the query and play around the front end coding (C#) to insert into the DataTable.**

Comment: do you  use MySQL or MariaDB. MariaDB has a very nice SEQUENCE Engine to do things like this

Comment: I am using MySql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need list of months and `Left Join` your table with the months list to get the missing months with 0 count

```
SELECT a.`Month`,
       Count(t.`Month`)
FROM   (SELECT 'January' AS `Month`,1 as Month_No
        UNION ALL SELECT 'February',2
        UNION ALL SELECT 'March',3
        UNION ALL SELECT 'April',4
        UNION ALL SELECT 'May',5
        UNION ALL SELECT 'June',6
        UNION ALL SELECT 'July',7
        UNION ALL SELECT 'August',8
        UNION ALL SELECT 'September',9
        UNION ALL SELECT 'October',10
        UNION ALL SELECT 'November',11
        UNION ALL SELECT 'December',12) a
       LEFT JOIN tbl_test t
              ON t.`Month` = a.`Month`
                 AND t.id = " + id + "
                 AND t.Month IS NOT NULL
                 AND t.Year = " + Convert.ToInt32(currentYear) + "
GROUP  BY a.month,a.Month_No
Order by Month_No
```

**Note :** Add your table filter to `ON` condition don not add it in Where clause it will convert the `Left join` to `Inner join`

- [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a722/3)

Comment: Hey! 50K. Congratulations!  A well deserved achievement.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti - Thank you John.. Am sure you will reach it soon ;)

Comment: All rows returns zero when I run this.
bts congrates for 50K :)

Comment: @MahatmaAladdin - Make sure for the filters you pass some records present in `tbl_test` table

Comment: @Prdp Yes. Records are present only for May and December.

Comment: @MahatmaAladdin - Then it should work as expected. Here is a working demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a722/1

Comment: Hey. Thanks.Its working. Can we order it by month number. Right now its alphabetically ordered.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a month_table and the key between you `tbl_test`  and your  my_month_table is named month_key

you should use a join and eventually use ifnull for null month count

```
    select Month, ifnull(count(id), 0) transactions 
    from `tbl_test` 
    inner join my_month_table  as m on m.month_key = `tbl_test`.month_key 
    where id=" + id + " and Month is not NULL and Year = " + Convert.ToInt32(currentYear) + " 
    group by Month;
```